# Images not painting/loading right away in Swing Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, image, swing, desktop-application, loading

When I run my Java Desktop Application created with Netbean's Swing, the JLabel icon images load right away but the background images on my JPanel don't paint to the screen until I wake-up (re-size) the window.

**Here is the custom code on my JPanel:**

```
Image image = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/background.gif"));
javax.swing.JPanel panelBackground = new BackgroundPanel(image);
```

Is there a better way to call the image? Is there image handling code I should be implementing?

How should I fix it?

Comment: wrote "Is there a better way to call the image? ", I think that not, that LayoutManagers issue http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html tons of examples for that on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm

Comment: What happens if you use ImageIO.read(...) to get your image? Also, are you adding the image-displaying component to the GUI after it has been rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Many thanks to ***Hovercraft Full Of Eels*** for the pointer

> "What happens if you use ImageIO.read(...) to get your image? Also, are you adding the image-displaying component to the GUI after it has been rendered?"

And to ***camickr*** for the code to think on.

I resolved it by using:

```
    Image imgBackground = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/background.gif"));
```

Creating and assigning the image to the variable at the beginning of my class instead of in the JPanels custom code section also worked. That is because the image had more time to be created..

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me. I tested it using the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/). Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you still have a problem.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BackgroundSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public BackgroundSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        Image duke = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("dukeWaveRed.gif"));
        BackgroundPanel test = new BackgroundPanel(duke, BackgroundPanel.ACTUAL, 1.0f, 0.5f);
        add(test);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BackgroundSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new BackgroundSSCCE() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```